# CSS doesn't load on other devices available within LAN

Tags: moqui

If I access application developed in moqui on LAN, CSS and stylings of any page doesn't load.

Is it something to do with the framework configurations, if not what might be the possible solution to rectify this thing.

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: There are various possible reasons for this. What do the URLs look like in the generated HTML?